# Save draft emails from Laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel, email

**Trying to figure out if there is an elegant way to "save" HTML string as an email message body in the "Drafts" folder of my mailbox.**

IMAP can be a possible option. But, do not want to use php_imap() as it is getting painful to configure it on my MacOS Mojave.

Also, was trying to figure out [zend-mail](https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-mail/read/#using-remote-storage-protocols), but can't find good example of how can I do this.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: why not save in database?

Comment: @Gabriel - No, I want to save in some system account's mailbox; so that users of my application can review and send from there. My application can't send the email as recipients of this email will be confidential and users are not willing to input receipients inside my application (so is a difficult situation)

Answer (score 1):

I have a workaround.

Controller:

```html
 try {
    Mail::to([])->send(new MailTemplate($this, $filename));
} catch (\Swift_TransportException $e) {}
```

Mail Template

```html
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class MailTemplate extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $order;
    public $filename;

    /**
     * MailTemplate constructor.
     * @param Order $order
     * @param $filename
     */
    public function __construct(Order $order, $filename)
    {
        $this->order = $order;
        $this->filename = $filename;

        $this->withSwiftMessage(function ($message) {
            $email = $this->order->id . '.eml';
            $path = 'email/' . $email;
            Storage::put($path , $message->toString());
        });
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        $subject = 'Notification: ';
        $this->cc($this->order->requestor->email);
        if ($this->filename !== null)
            $this->attach($this->filename);

        return $this->subject($subject)->view('emails.apac', ['order' => $this->order]);
    }
}
```

You will find an email draft in you storage/app/

Comment: Well, I don't want to store the draft in /storage/app folder. I want it to be inside "Drafts" folder of the specified mailbox.